# If $|f(a)| \leq a$ for every $z$ on $K$ with $\Im z \geq 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq b$ for every $z$ in $K$ with $\Im z \leq 0$, then $|f(0)| \leq \sqrt{ab}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Delta = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| <1\}$, $K= \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| =1\}$, and let $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$ be two constants.

A function $f$ is continuous on the closed disk $\bar \Delta$, is analytic in $\Delta$ and satisfies the conditions $|f(a)| \leq a$ for every $z$ on $K$ with $\Im z \geq 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq b$ for every $z$ in $K$ with $\Im z \leq 0$. Prove that $|f(0)| \leq \sqrt{ab}$. (**Hint:** Consider the function $g(z)=f(-z)$ along with $f$.)

I didn't figure out how to use the hint given, but I tried tried to do the proof un two ways:

1. Using a corollary of the maximum modulus principle, which states that *if $D$ is a bounded domain in the complex plane, and $f : \bar D \to \Bbb C$ is a continuous function that is analytic in $D$, then $|f(z)|$ reaches its maximum at some point of the boundary of $D$.* Using this corollary, I tried to to prove that $|f(0)| \leq a$ and $|f(0)| \leq b$, so we'd have $|f(0)|^2 \leq ab$ and the result would follow. The problem is that we only have $f(0) \leq \max\{a,b\}$, what if $f(0) >  \min\{a,b\}$?
2. I tried to use Cauchy's integral formula. Let $\gamma: [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb C$ defined by $\gamma (t) = e^{it}$. Also, let $\alpha: [0,\pi] \to \Bbb C$, $\alpha (t) = e^{it}$ and $\beta: [\pi,2\pi] \to \Bbb C$, $\beta (t) = e^{it}$. So, $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$. Then:

$$|f(0)| = \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)dz}{z-0} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\alpha \frac{f(z)dz}{z} +  \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\beta \frac{f(z)dz}{z}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\alpha \frac{|f(z)||dz|}{|z|} + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\beta \frac{|f(z)||dz|}{|z|} $$
$$ \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\alpha \frac{a|dz|}{1} + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\beta \frac{b|dz|}{1} = \leq \frac{a}{2 \pi} \int_\alpha |dz| + \frac{b}{2 \pi} \int_\beta |dz| = \frac{a}{2 \pi} \cdot \pi + \frac{b}{2 \pi} \cdot \pi = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2}.$$
I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) that $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$, but I need the reverse inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
H(z):=f(-z)f(z).
$$
Clearly
$$
|H(z)|=|f(-z)||f(z)|\le ab\;\;\forall z\in K
$$
thus, by MMP one has that $|H(z)|\le ab$ on the whole $\Delta$ and in particular
$$
|H(0)|\le ab
$$
but
$$
|H(0)|=|f(0)|^2
$$
and the claim follows.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I see I was complicating the problem a lot.

Comment: Why is H not constant?

Comment: @F.R. by definition of $H$